# Why is a cloudflare script being inserted into source for Drupal domain?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drupal, cloudflare, superfish

Code for a CloudFlare script is being inserted into the source for one of my sites (Drupal) and I do not know where it is coming from. Someone suggested that it may be related to a Superfish module but I have searched and can't find it. It appears to be the cause of some problems because it links to an old version of d3.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some time a Drupal module or theme must have installed the link to cloudflare in the the variable table in the Drupal mysql database (sometimes when a module is uninstalled it does not clean up 100%) I deleted the entry and the script isn't being inserted anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have Rocket Loader enabled in your CloudFlare settings. Check that and report back. There might be other settings causing it as well. Can you post the website so I can check further?

Comment: Actually I managed to find the cause. I never had any CloudFlare installed so I have no settings but at some time a Drupal module or theme installed the link to cloudflare in the the variable table in the Drupal mysql database. I deleted the entry and the script isn't being inserted anymore. [I have other problems now (XSS Auditor) which I am working on. The javascript files have references to w3.org which I think are causing the problem so I am working on that now.]